# Iphone SDK - Communicating between objects

Tags: iphone

In the below application you can see my current setup where the application launches and depending on whether the user is logged in or not a different uiviewcontroller is added as a subview of the main application [window addSubview:[loggedOutController view]];
My question is within -View1 (Login Screen), once the user attempts to login and it is successful, how can I go back to root level MainApplication and instead of loading the LoggedOut UIVIewcontroller now instead load in the LoggedIn UIViewController? It's unclear to me how to communicate accross.

```
MainApplication
    - UIViewController (Logged Out)
        -UINavController
            -View1 (Login Screen)
                -View1a (Register Screen)
    - UIViewController (Logged In) 
        -UITabBarController
            -View1 (Settings)
                -UINavController (Handle edit Profile Settings)
                    - View 1
                        -View 1a
                        -View 1b
                        -View 1c
            -View2
```

Comment: I just found out about NSNotificationCenter seems like this will work, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are a multitude of ways to do this. One way to pass information between views is by setting a delegate object. So for instance, create a MainViewController delegate object in LoginScreen, and upon successful login, you can call `[delegate onSuccessfulLogin]`, which will can pop the view stack and run the LoggedIn view controller.

Comment: Thanks B_ does that mean I need to set every object below UIViewController as a delegate of the next and implement functions to pass the data back to UIViewController one object at a time or is there a more direct way back to UIViewController without having to touch each object in between?

Comment: If your structure needs to pass objects very far back, there are other things you can do. Your main view controller object can be a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which basically means you create an instance of the object within its class and function that returns that instance. You can also create a static class where you can set flags for whether you're logged in, etc, and check those flags when appropriate.